# QML TextArea: different behavior when using QtQuick.Controls > 2.0 vs 1.4

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I'm new to Qml but I wanted to give it a try to see if it's worth using it in place of the old Qt Widgets, especially because I've heard it's better for mobile devices. I'm using Qml for the GUI alongside a couple of C++ classes for the core logic.
I needed a scrollable TextArea, as in a text editor, so I found that I had to use a TextArea nested in a ScrollView, like this:

```
ScrollView {
    ...
    TextArea {
        ...
    }
}
```

I liked the result in my dark QML app, with a nice looking text editor and nice scroll bars on my dark background.

The problem came up when I needed to implement a *scrollTo* function in my code. My app is a sort of player that highlights the text and scrolls down when it reaches a 1/4 of the height. I found that I could use the *flickableItem.contentY* property to adjust the relative position of the text in my ScrollView, but the property wasn't there even though other answers referred to it.

I reached Qt documentation and there was no sign of it, only a contentItem property. So I tried to adjust the *contentItem.y* property but the result was awful. The text and the whole background were panning, covering my top toolbar.

So I searched the docs for other implementations of TextArea and found that *QtQuick.Controls 1.4* had a TextArea implementation that inherited the ScrollView class. That was the solution, I thought. I switched to the older implementation and managed to make the whole thing work. Now I can scroll my TextArea programmatically through the *flickableItem.contentY* property, and the *contentHeight* vs *height* properties to calculate how much room I have.

The problem here is that the 1.4 version has ugly looking scrollbars, and I feel like it's kind of a hack to use the older one. Is there a reason why they dropped the *flickableItem* property from the ScrollView? Is there another way to do the same thing with the new Controls versions?

Here is my code:

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.12

TextArea {
    id: textArea

    anchors.fill: parent
    backgroundVisible: false

    /*background: Rectangle {
        anchors.fill: parent
        color: "#000000"
    }*/

    //color: "#ffffff"

    textColor: "#ffffff"
    selectByKeyboard: true
    selectByMouse: true
    verticalScrollBarPolicy: Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn

    function scrollToY(y) {
        if ((contentHeight-y) > flickableItem.height && y > flickableItem.height/4) {
            flickableItem.contentY = y - flickableItem.height/4
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So in simple you want a scrollable textArea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the reasoning behind implementation changes between Qt Quick Controls 1 and Qt Quick Controls 2. However, `ScrollView` in  Qt Quick Controls 2 can be programmatically scrolled through `ScrollBar.vertical.position`. I wrote an example code which moves the content using a timer until it's scrolled down, when the timer stops. Note, that if the content fits to the visible area then scrollbar is disabled and timer is not started because there is no need for moving the content. You can test that by changing boolean `useLongText` value to false.

```
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 400
    height: 400
    color: "blue"
    property string exampleTextShort: "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry."

    property string exampleTextLong: "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.

Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.

It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.

It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
"

    property bool useLongText: true // Change this to test with short text too

    Timer {
        id: timer
        running: scrollView.wholeTextSeen ? false : true
        repeat: true
        interval: 2000
        onTriggered: {
            scrollView.scrollDown()
        }
    }

    Rectangle{
        id: rect
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        width: parent.width*0.2;
        height: parent.height*0.2;
        ScrollView {
            id: scrollView
            anchors.fill: parent
            clip: true
            property bool wholeTextSeen: ScrollBar.vertical.size >= 1 ? true : false
            ScrollBar.vertical.policy: ScrollBar.vertical.size >= 1 ? ScrollBar.AlwaysOff : ScrollBar.AlwaysOn
            TextArea {
                readOnly: true
                text: useLongText ? exampleTextLong : exampleTextShort
                wrapMode: Text.WordWrap
            }

            function scrollDown() {
                if (wholeTextSeen) {
                    timer.running = false
                } else {
                    var scrollVar = ScrollBar.vertical.position + ScrollBar.vertical.size
                    console.log("scrollVar:",scrollVar)
                    if (scrollVar >= 1) {
                        wholeTextSeen = true
                    } else {
                        var step = 0.2
                        step = scrollVar + step > 1 ? 1 - scrollVar : step
                        ScrollBar.vertical.position = ScrollBar.vertical.position + step
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Example output when running the long text looks like this for me:

```
qml: scrollVar: 0.15625
qml: scrollVar: 0.35625
qml: scrollVar: 0.55625
qml: scrollVar: 0.7562500000000001
qml: scrollVar: 0.95625
qml: scrollVar: 1
```

Comment: thank you so much. `ScrollBar.vertical.position` was exactly what I was searching for. In your snippet you scroll the text at an arbitrary rate, while I need to scroll down the amount of 1 exact text line and only if it's > 1/4 of the height of the visible textArea. That should be easy to find out though. Just out of curiosity, doesn't the keyword `ScrollBar`, which is a type name, declare a new child? Shouldn't it be a property name as, for instance, `scrollBar`?

Comment: `ScrollBar.vertical` is so called attached property in ScrollView. You can read more about attached properties from the [Qt documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-objectattributes.html#attached-properties-and-attached-signal-handlers). So, you need to set position property of that attached property to get content moving in vertical direction programmatically.

Comment: Thank you again. As you probably noticed I'm pretty new to Qml language, but I'm a quick learner and I already managed to create a nice app with it. I still prefer to code core stuff in C++ because I'm kind of old school, but I appreciate the nice UI features of QtQuick, and Qml reduces the effort.